# The IHIH Pyramid

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, fractal

I find it fascinating how the letters "H" and "I" are very similar. "H" is a horizontal stroke surrounded by two vertical strokes; "I" is a vertical stroke surrounded by two horizontal strokes (depending on your font). I bet this could be nested... You know what that reminds me of? **Fractals**!!!

Let's define the "IHIH" pyramid as follows: The first iteration is this ASCII representation of the letter "I":

```
---
 |
---
```

The next iteration has a vertical stroke on either side.

```
|   |
|---|
| | |
|---|
|   |
```

If you view the "I" in the middle as a single horizontal stroke, then this second iteration is basically an "H". The third iteration adds a horizontal stroke on the top and bottom

```
-------
 |   |
 |---|
 | | |
 |---|
 |   |
-------
```

Again, if you view the "H" in the middle as a single vertical stroke, then this iteration is basically an "I". This pattern continues, alternating between "H"s and "I"s on every iteration. For reference, here are the first 6 iterations:

```
1:
---
 |
---

2:
|   |
|---|
| | |
|---|
|   |

3:
-------
 |   |
 |---|
 | | |
 |---|
 |   |
-------

4:
|       |
|-------|
| |   | |
| |---| |
| | | | |
| |---| |
| |   | |
|-------|
|       |

5:
-----------
 |       |
 |-------|
 | |   | |
 | |---| |
 | | | | |
 | |---| |
 | |   | |
 |-------|
 |       |
-----------

6:
|           |
|-----------|
| |       | |
| |-------| |
| | |   | | |
| | |---| | |
| | | | | | |
| | |---| | |
| | |   | | |
| |-------| |
| |       | |
|-----------|
|           |
```

## The Challenge:

Write a program or function that outputs the *N'th* iteration of the IHIH pyramid, and an optional trailing newline. Your input will be a single positive integer in whatever reasonable format you want. You do not have to handle invalid inputs, e.g. non-integers, numbers smaller than 1, etc. Your program must at the very least produce the right output for inputs up to 20. Since this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), standard loopholes are not allowed and the shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: Is it acceptable if I return an arrow of strings one fror each row?

Comment: Didn't quite meeting the challenge criteria, but did something cool by accident... [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fzkepRkFXSfnQzkcdvcWHpx9pLy6rfNQw6/QcPaegc9tq9R51zAPirv//jYwB "05AB1E – Try It Online")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>50</s> <s>40</s> <s>31</s> 25 bytes

```
j@s.u,J+*\-K+2lheN+jR*2;eN*\-KjR"||"+*dK+J*dKQ]]\|
LXR"|-")CbjyW%Q2uy+K*\-+2lhG+jR*2;GKQ]\|
juCGQuC+K*@"-|"H+3yH+jR*2;GKQ\|
j@CBujR*@"-|"H2CjR*2;GQ\|
```

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=j%40CBujR%2a%40%22-%7C%22H2CjR%2a2%3BGQ%5C%7C&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A4&debug=0)

#### Explanation

This is a recursive algorithm.

In each iteration, we perform three actions:

1. prepend and append a space to each line
2. transpose the array
3. prepend and append to each line either `"-"` or `"|"` depending on the number of iteration.

After the iterations, the odd-numbered outputs will be transposed. Therefore, we transpose them.

```
j@CBujR*@"-|"H2CjR*2;GQ\|   input: Q
j@CBujR*@"-|"H2CjR*2;GQ\|Q  implicit filling of arguments


    u                 Q\|   for Q times, starting with "|", G as current output,
                            H as number of iterations:

                jR*2;G          prepend and append a space to each line
                                (using each line as separator, join [" "," "])
               C                transpose
     jR*      2                 prepend and append the following to each line:
        @"-|"H                      the H-th element of the string "-|" (modular indexing)

 @CB                     Q  select the Q-th element from [output,
                            transposed output] (modular indexing)
j                           join by newlines
```

Comment: I love the transponation idea.

Answer (score 12):

## Python, <s>165</s> <s>145</s> <s>133</s> 123 bytes

A recursive solution:

```python
def i(e):
 d="|";a=e*2;x=d+" "*(a-1)+d
 if e<1:return d
 if e%2:d,x=[" ","-"*(a+1)]
 return[x]+[d+z+d for z in i(e-1)]+[x]
```

Called with `print ("\n".join(i(int(sys.argv[1]))))`, where the parameter is the iteration number of the IHIH pyramid.

Thanks to @DJMcMayhem for saving 20 bytes. Taking the idea behind those suggestions further saved another 12 bytes. Thanks to @Maltysen for suggestions that trimmed some more bytes.

The function sets the delimiter `d` to `"|"` and the intervening spaces to `" "` (for odd-numbered iterations), deals with returning in the degenerate case, then resets the delimiter to `" "` and the intervening spaces to `"-"` for even-numbered iterations. The function returns a list of strings for each line of the IHIH, having embedded the result of a recursive call to the function in the right place within the list.

Comment: Nice answer, and welcome to the site! You do not need to join the lines, a list of strings is fine. A couple tips: change lines 2 and 3 to `if e<1:return'|'` (no newline between them) then remove the "else" and remove the extra indentation.

Comment: you can take out the space after `return`. Also, you can merge the lines without `if`s with semicolons, and save on the indentation

Comment: I've edited your answer. Please feel free to revert my edits if you don't like them.

Answer (score 10):

## [Cheddar](https://github.com/cheddar-lang/Cheddar), <s>186</s> <s>177</s> <s>165</s> <s>154</s> <s>148</s> 131 bytes

```
(n,b?,c?,q?,g=s->(n-=1)<0?s:g((q=(c=s.lines[0].len)%4>2?b='|'+" "*c+"|":b='-'*(c+2))+"\n"+s.sub(/^|$/gm,q?'|':' ')+"\n"+b))->g("|")
```

Uses recursion. Will add explanation once done golfing.

[Try it online!](http://cheddar.tryitonline.net/#code=KG4sYj8sYz8scT8sZz1zLT4obi09MSk8MD9zOmcoKHE9KGM9cy5saW5lc1swXS5sZW4pJTQ-Mj9iPSd8JysiICIqYysifCI6Yj0nLScqKGMrMikpKyJcbiIrcy5zdWIoL158JC9nbSxxPyd8JzonICcpKyJcbiIrYikpLT5nKCJ8Iik&input=MQ)

### Explanation

This one is a bit complex too keep track off all the variables I'm using but I'll try to keep it simple:

```
(
 n,    // Input
 b?,   // Stores row to add to top/bottom
 c?,   // Width of string 
 q?,   // false if I-ifying. true if not
 g=
   s->          // Main logic, s is generated string
    (n-=1)<0 ? s :   // Decrease input each iteration. Stop when 0
    g(               // Recurse with....
      (
        q= (         // Set `q` true if h-ifying. false if I-ifying
         c=s.lines[0].len    // Set `c` to width of string
        ) % 4>2 ?
        b='|'+" "*c+"|" :    // Set `b` to top/bottom row adding
        b='-'*(c+2)          // `*` is repeat, c is from before
      ) + "\n" + 
        s.sub(/^|$/gm,       // Add the following to beginning/end of each line
          q?'|':' '          // if H-ifying, add `|`s if I-ifying add spaces
        ) + "\n" + b         // Add bottom row, generated from before
    )
) -> g("|")     // Middle item is `|`
```

This was a pain to golf but its 55 bytes shorter than original.

Answer (score 8):

## Python 2, 93 bytes

Leaky Nun saved 7 bytes.

```python
r=range(input()+1)
r=r[:0:-1]+r
for y in r:print''.join('| -'[[x%2,y%2+1][x&-2<y]]for x in r)
```

Comment: Closed form :o :o

Comment: Ahh, of course: at first I needed `int(x/2.)` because I was taking `range(-n,n+1)` but now I can just use those. Thank you!

Comment: I specified Python 2 in the header because simply saying "Python" usually means the code works under either Python 2 or Python 3, which is not the case here.

Answer (score 7):

## [Matricks](https://github.com/jediguy13/Matricks), <s>80</s> 62 bytes

An iterative solution (Recursion in Matricks is hard...)

Run with `python matricks.py ihih.txt [[]] <input> --asciiprint`

```
k124;FiQ%2:v;b[m124:Q*2+3:1;];a{z:Q*2+1;};:b;v[m45:1:Q*2+3;];u{zQ*2+1:;};;:1:n;;
k124;FiQ%2:v;b[m124:Q*2+3:2;];B1;:b;v[m45:2:Q*2+3;];V1;;:1:n;;
```

Explanation:

```
k124;                 # Set the matrix to '|'
F...:1:n;;            # Repeat input times, (Q is iteration variable)
  iQ%2:...:...;       # if statement, check if Q is odd or even
                      # Q is even,
    b;                # Make space to the left
    v[m45:2:Q*2+3;];  # Set the top 2 rows to '-'s
    V1;               # Rotate the matrix up 1 unit, moving the topmost row to the bottom
                      # Q is odd,
    v;                # Make space above
    b[m124:Q*2+3:2;]; # Set the 2 left columns to '|'s
    B1;               # Rotate the matrix left 1 unit, moving the leftmost row to the right
```

Comment: Wow, iterative! I'm impressed.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Matricks was built for dynamic matrix resizing, so it's not THAT impressive, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>92</s> 90 bytes

```js
f=
(n,[h,c,v]=n&1?`-- `:` ||`)=>n?(c+=h.repeat(n+n-1)+c)+`
${f(n-1).replace(/^|$/gm,v)}
`+c:v
;
```

```html
<input type=number min=0 oninput=o.textContent=f(+this.value)><pre id=o>
```

Recursive solution works by taking the previous iteration, adding the `v` character to the sides, then adding the `c` character to the corners and the `h` character along the top and bottom. The set of characters simply alternates each iteration. Edit: Saved 2 bytes by returning `v` when `n=0`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), <s>52</s> 43 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

```apl
{v=⊃⍵:h⍪⍨h⍪s,⍵,s⋄v,⍨v,s⍪⍵⍪s}⍣⎕⍪⊃v h s←'|- '
```

`v h s←'|- '` assigns the three characters to three names (**v**ertical, **h**orizontal, **s**pace)

`⊃` the first one, i.e. `|`

`⍪` make into 1×1 table

`{`...`}⍣⎕` get input and apply the braced function that many times

`v=⊃⍵:` if the top-left character of the argument is a vertical, then:

`h⍪⍨` horizontals below

`h⍪` horizontals above

`s,` spaces to the left of

`⍵,s` the argument with spaces to the right

`⋄` else:

`v,⍨` verticals to the right of

`v,` verticals to the left of

`s⍪` spaces above

`⍵⍪s` the argument with spaces below

[TryAPL online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=%u2355%7B%7Bv%3D%u2283%u2375%3Ah%u236A%u2368h%u236As%2C%u2375%2Cs%u22C4v%2C%u2368v%2Cs%u236A%u2375%u236As%7D%u2363%u2375%u236A%u2283v%20h%20s%u2190%27%7C-%20%27%7D%A81%202%203%204%205%206&run)

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 84 bytes

```
,[[["|"]]:?:1]i:1:zi:ca~@nw
hh~m["-|":B]:ramggL," "ggS,?:Sz:ca:Srz:caz:Lz:ca:Lrz:ca.
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=LFtbWyJ8Il1dOj86MV1pOjE6emk6Y2F-QG53Cmhofm1bIi18IjpCXTpyYW1nZ0wsIiAiZ2dTLD86U3o6Y2E6U3J6OmNhejpMejpjYTpMcno6Y2Eu&input=Mw)

A port of [my answer in Pyth](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90293/48934).

Answer (score 3):

## C, 110 bytes

```
#define R(A,B,C)for(A=n,B=1;A<=n;putchar(C),A-=B|=-!A)
f(n,y,x,w,v){R(y,w,10)R(x,v,"| -"[x/2*2<y?y%2+1:x%2]);}
```

Invoke as `f(n)`. For 111 bytes, I could do:

```
f(n,y,x,w,v){for(y=n,w=1;y<=n;y-=w|=-!y,puts(""))for(x=n,v=1;x<=n;x-=v|=-!x)putchar("| -"[x/2*2<y?y%2+1:x%2]);}
```

i.e., the `#define` saves exactly one byte.

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 34 bytes

```apl
'- |'[2+∘.(≤-(1+=)×2|⌈)⍨(⌽,0,⊢)⍳⎕]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob2pm/qO2CYZcjzra0/6r6yrUqEcbaT/qmKGn8ahzia6Gobat5uHpRjWPejo0H/Wu0HjUs1fHQOdR1yIgbzNQd@x/oMb/6UAjHvX2GQJl1Wur1XXUgTIgXKT@qHerOlC10aOe7UB@cpF6mrrCo965CiVFiSlpeQol@QpAiiv90AqgcaYA)

(uses `⎕io←1`)

`⍳⎕` is `1 2 ... N`

`(⌽,0,⊢)` is a train that turns it into `-N ... -1 0 1 ... N`

`∘.( )⍨` executes the parentheses for every pair of coordinates `⍺ ⍵`

the train `(≤-(1+=)×2|⌈)` or its dfn equivalent `{(⍺≤⍵)-(1+⍺=⍵)×2|⍺⌈⍵}` produces a matrix like:

```apl
 ¯1 ¯1 ¯1 ¯1 ¯1 ¯1 ¯1 ¯1 ¯1 ¯1 ¯1
  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
  0  1 ¯1 ¯1 ¯1 ¯1 ¯1 ¯1 ¯1  1  0
  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  1  0
  0  1  0  1 ¯1 ¯1 ¯1  1  0  1  0
  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0
  0  1  0  1 ¯1 ¯1 ¯1  1  0  1  0
  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  1  0
  0  1 ¯1 ¯1 ¯1 ¯1 ¯1 ¯1 ¯1  1  0
  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
 ¯1 ¯1 ¯1 ¯1 ¯1 ¯1 ¯1 ¯1 ¯1 ¯1 ¯1
```

`'- |'[2+   ]` makes these valid indices in `⎕IO=1` and picks the corresponding characters

Comment: A rare occurrence where a full program and dfn have the same bytecount.

Answer (score 3):

## Dyalog APL, 34 bytes

```
{⍉⍣⍵{b,b,⍨⍉s,⍵,⊃s b←' -|'~⊃⍵}⍣⍵⍪'|'}
```

`{`...`}⍣⍵⍪'|'` Apply function in braces `⍵` times starting with 1x1 matrix of character `|`. The result of each application is the argument for the next application.

`s b←' -|'~⊃⍵` s is space and b is the bar not in the top left corner of the argument (`' -|'~'-'` removes horizontal bar and leaves space and vertical bar)

`s,⍵,⊃s b` add space to left and right (`⊃` picks s from vector s b)

`b,b,⍨⍉` transpose and add b to left and right

For odd numbers this leaves the result transposed, so a final transpose is required.

`⍉⍣⍵` Transpose `⍵` times (once would be enough, but shorter to code this way)

[TryAPL online](http://tryapl.org/?a=%7B%u2349%u2363%u2375%7Bb%2Cb%2C%u2368%u2349s%2C%u2375%2C%u2283s%20b%u2190%27%20-%7C%27~%u2283%u2375%7D%u2363%u2375%u236A%27%7C%27%7D5&run)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: Thanks! Trying to join the party now, lots of fun solving these :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Cheddar](http://cheddar.vihan.org/), 107 bytes

```
(n,g=n->n?(f->f(f(g(n-1)," ").turn(1),n%2?"-":"|"))((a,b)->a.map(i->b+i+b)):["|"])->(n%2?g(n).turn(1):g(n))
```

[Try it online!](http://cheddar.tryitonline.net/#code=dmFyIGYgPSAobixnPW4tPm4_KGYtPmYoZihnKG4tMSksIiAiKS50dXJuKDEpLG4lMj8iLSI6InwiKSkoKGEsYiktPmEubWFwKGktPmIraStiKSk6WyJ8Il0pLT4obiUyP2cobikudHVybigxKTpnKG4pKTsKCm4tPnByaW50KGYobikudmZ1c2Up&input=NA)

Answer (score 2):

## Cheddar, 85 bytes

```
(n,r=(-n|>n).map(v->abs v))->r.map(y->r.map(x->"| -"[(x&-2)<y?y%2+1:x%2]).fuse).vfuse
```

My first Cheddar answer. [Try it online!](http://cheddar.tryitonline.net/#code=cHJpbnQoKAogIChuLHI9KC1ufD5uKS5tYXAodi0-YWJzIHYpKS0-ci5tYXAoeS0-ci5tYXAoeC0-InwgLSJbKHgmLTIpPHk_eSUyKzE6eCUyXSkuZnVzZSkudmZ1c2UKKSgxMSkpOw&input=&debug=on)

If I try to write `r=(-n|>n).map(v->abs v).map`, and then `r(y->r(x->…))`, the interpreter crashes. ;-;

Comment: You can make `v->abs v` into `(abs)` (e.g. `r.map((abs))`) which will return a function which has the behavior of the abs function. e.g. `(+)(1,2)` -> `3`. `(^)(2,6)` -> 64. Also big wow on outgolfing me by almost 50%

Comment: No, I tried that: ``Runtime Error: `abs` has no behavior for types `Number` and `Number` `` (because `map` receives both the element and its index, presumably.)

Comment: ah :/ i was just about to fix that bug today >_>

Answer (score 1):

### MATLAB, <strike>168</strike> 163 bytes

This is probably not the cleverest way to do it: Expanding a string on all sides in `n` steps:

```
function s=g(n);s='|';for m=1:n;if mod(m,2);a=45;b=a;c=0;else a='|';b=0;c=a;end;s=[a repmat(b,1,2*m-1);repmat(c,2*m-1,1) s];s(:,end+1)=s(:,1);s(end+1,:)=s(1,:);end
```

Usage: Save as `g.m` (do I have to add that to the byte count?) and call e.g. `g(15)`.

Ungolfed:

```
function s=g(n)

% // Initialize s
s = '|';

for m=1:n
   % // Decide if odd or even number and which symbol to add where
   if mod(m,2)
      a=45;b=a;c=0; % // char(45) is '-' and char(0) is ' ' (thx to Luis Mendo)
   else
      a='|';b=0;c=a;
   end
      % // Add symbols at top and left to s
      s = [a repmat(b,1,2*m-1);repmat(c,2*m-1,1) s];
      % // Add symbols at right and bottom to s
      s(:,end+1) = s(:,1);
      s(end+1,:) = s(1,:);
end
```

Comment: You can replace `' '` by `0` (Matlab treats char 0 as a space) and `'-'`  by `45`. File name doesn't have to be included in byte count

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, <s>81</s> <s>78</s> 77 bytes

This is based on [Lynn's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/90311/47581). Golfing suggestions welcome.

**Edit:** 3 bytes thanks to Lynn. Corrections and golfing 1 byte thanks to Jordan.

```ruby
->n{r=(-n..n).map &:abs;r.map{|y|puts r.map{|x|"| -"[x&-2<y ?y%2+1:x%2]}*""}}
```

**Ungolfing:**

```ruby
def f(n)
  r = -n..n            # Range from -n to n (inclusive)
  r = r.map{|i|i.abs}  # Turns every element of r positive
  r.each do |y|
    s = ""             # a line of the fractal
    r.each do |x|      # build up the fractal based on x and y
      if x/2*2 < y
        s += " -"[y%2]
      else
        s += "| "[x%2]
      end
    end
    puts s             # print the line
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you `.map(&:abs)`?

Comment: @Lynn Well spotted. Any other suggestions?

Comment: The first `*` isn't doing anything. You can use `*""` instead of `.join`. Also, using `p` surrounds each line with quotation marks (it calls `inspect` on its arguments), which might disqualify you.

Comment: Also, you can remove the parentheses around `&:abs` (`map &:abs`). You might be able to do something with `Array#product` instead of nested `map`s, but it'll make line breaks tricky.

Comment: @Jordan Your first four hints work, but `r.product(r).map` (however that works) is longer and does not appear to allow line breaks very easily.

Answer (score 1):

## [Actually](http://github.com/Mego/Seriously), <s>48</s> <s>45</s> 44 bytes

This is an attempt to port my Ruby answer to Actually. This is way too long and golfing suggestions are very much appreciated. [Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=dTvCsXV44pmCQeKVl-KVnGDilZ3ilZwiOzJAJTLilZsldeKVmygywrEmPEknLScgJ3wrK0UiwqNNzqMuYE0&input=NQ)

```
u;±ux♂A╗╜`╝╜";2@%2╛%u╛(2±&<I'-' '|++E"£MΣ.`M
```

Here is a 46-byte version which separates out the nested functions so that we can define `"| -"` in fewer bytes. [Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=dTvCsXV44pmCQeKVl-KVnGA7MkAlMuKVmyV14pWbKDLCsSY8SSJ8IC0iRWAjIuKVneKVnCVywqNNzrVqLiIlwqNN&input=NQ)

```
u;±ux♂A╗╜`;2@%2╛%u╛(2±&<I"| -"E`#"╝╜%r£MΣ."%£M
```

**Ungolfing:**

First algorithm

```
u         Increment implicit input.
;±u       Duplicate, negate, increment. Stack: [-n n+1]
x♂A       Range [-n, n+1). Abs(x) over the range.
╗         Save list to register 0. Let's call it res.
╜         Push res so we can iterate over it.
  `         Start function (with y from map() at the end)
  ╝         Save y to register 1.
  ╜         Push res so we can iterate over it.
    "         Start function as string (with x from map() at the end)
    ;         Duplicate x.
    2@%       x mod 2.
    2╛%u      y mod 2 + 1.
    ╛(2±&<I   If x&-2 < y, then y%2+1, else x%2.
    '-' '|++  Push "| -" (We're inside a string right now,
                          so we need to push each char individually)
    E         Grab index of "| -"
    "£        End string and turn into function.
  M         Map over res.
  Σ.        sum() (into a string) and print.
  `         End function.
M         Map over res.
```

Second algorithm

```
u;±ux♂A╗╜                  Create res as before.
`;2@%2╛%u╛(2±&<I"| -"E`#   The inner function from the first algorithm put into a list.
                             The only change to the function is the definition of "| -".
"╝╜  £MΣ."                 Most of the outer function from the first algorithm as a string.
   %r      %               %-formats the list into the outer function.
            £M             Turns the string into a function, maps over res.
```

Comment: `u;±ux♂A╗╜\`;2@%2╛%u╛(2±&<I"| -"E\`#"╝╜%r£Mεj."%£M` is longer than what you currently have (by 2 bytes), but you might find some inspiration for ways to make it shorter that I'm not seeing.

Answer (score 1):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), <s>19</s> <s>18</s> <s>17</s> 14 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
|╶［ ｅ↷ｌ|＊ｅ｝╶［↷
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JTdDJXUyNTc2JXVGRjNCJTIwJXVGRjQ1JXUyMUI3JXVGRjRDJTdDJXVGRjBBJXVGRjQ1JXVGRjVEJXUyNTc2JXVGRjNCJXUyMUI3,i=Mw__,v=2)

If I were allowed to output every other output rotated 90°, the last 4 characters could be removed.

Explanation (some characters have been changed to look ~monospace):

```
|               push "|" - the canvas
 ╶[       }     repeat input times
    e             encase the canvas in spaces horizontally
     ↷            rotate the canvas 90°
      l|*         push "-" repeated the canvas height times vertically
         e        and encase the canvas if two of those horizontally
           ╶[   repeat input times
             ↷    rotate the canvas 90°
```

Comment: I'd lose 6 bytes if they loosened that restriction too :P.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn wellp, make that -5 bytes for me :p (could your answer benefit from a transpose loop as well?)

Comment: my implementation **is** a transpose loop :D.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>29</s> 28 bytes

```
„|-S¹>∍ƶćsvy‚˜.Bζ}¹Fζ}»R.∞.∊
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UcO8Gt3gQzvtHnX0Htt2pL24rPJRw6zTc/Sczm2rPbTTDUTuDtJ71DEPiLv@/zcFAA)

-1 thanks to Dzaima...

This is an iterative solution.

---

Essentially This is made by creating the following pattern:

```
['|','--','|||',...]
```

Then, pairwise, transposing each element together and adding the padding.

By transposing after each iteration, we end up creating a single corner of the pattern.

Then, we can use 05AB1E's reflection commands.

---

```
„|-S                         # Push ['|','-']
    ¹>∍                      # Extended to input length.
       ƶ                     # Each element multiplied by its index.
        ćs                   # Extract head of list, swap remainder to top.
          v      }           # For each element in the '|-' list...
           y‚˜               # Wrap current 2D array with new entry, flatten.
              .Bζ            # Pad and transpose, leaving it transposed for the next addition.
                 }           # End loop.
                  ¹Fζ}       # Transpose N times.
                      »R     # Bring it all together into a newline string, reverse.
                        .∞.∊ # Mirror horizontally, then vertically with overlap.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 22 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
âeò↕\┐▄┤╚╬8φ8Δ☺Pä≤δ₧ßƒ
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=836595125cbfdcb4c8ce38ed38ff015084f3eb9ee19f&i=1%0A2%0A3%0A4&a=1&m=2)

Unpacked, ungolfed, and commented, it looks like this.

```
'|          string literal "|"
{           begin block to repeat
  . |G      push " |", then jump to trailing `}` below 
  '-z2lG    push ["-",[]], then jump to trailing `}` below again
}N          repeat block according to number specified in input
m           output each row in grid

}           goto target - `G` from above jumps to here
  i@        modularly index into pair using iteration index
  ~         push to input stack
  {;|Sm     surround each row with the extracted element
  M         transpose grid
```

[Run this one](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%27%7C++++++%09string+literal+%22%7C%22%0A%7B+++++++%09begin+block+to+repeat%0A++.+%7CG++%09push+%22+%7C%22,+then+jump+to+trailing+%60%7D%60+below+%0A++%27-z2lG%09push+[%22-%22,[]],+then+jump+to+trailing+%60%7D%60+below+again%0A%7DN++++++%09repeat+block+according+to+number+specified+in+input%0Am+++++++%09output+each+row+in+grid%0A++++++++%09%0A%7D+++++++%09goto+target+-+%60G%60+from+above+jumps+to+here%0A++i%40++++%09modularly+index+into+pair+using+iteration+index%0A++~+++++%09push+to+input+stack%0A++%7B%3B%7CSm+%09surround+each+row+with+the+extracted+element%0A++M+++++%09transpose+grid&i=1%0A2%0A3%0A4&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, <s>158</s> 164 bytes

```
f[n_]:=Print/@StringJoin/@Map[{{{"|","|", },{ , , }},{{"|", ,"-"},{ ,"-","-"}}}[[##]]&@@#&,Table[{1+i~Mod~2, 1+j~Mod~2, 2+Sign[Abs[i]-Abs[j]]}, {i,-n,n}, {j,-n,n}],{2}]
```

Mathematically calculates the correct symbol at the coordinates (i,j), where both run from -n to n. Human formatted:

```
f[n_]:=Print/@
 StringJoin/@
  Map[
   {{{"|","|", },{ , , }},{{"|", ,"-"},{ ,"-","-"}}[[##]]&@@#&,
   Table[{1+i~Mod~2,1+j~Mod~2,2+Sign[Abs[i]-Abs[j]]},{i,-n,n},{j,-n,n}],
   {2}]
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 166 bytes

golfed more than 100 bytes off my first approach
and it´s still the longest answer here.

```
function i($n){for($m=['|'];$k++<$n;){array_unshift($m,$m[]=str_repeat(' -'[$f=$k&1],2*$k-1));foreach($m as$i=>&$r)$r=($c='||- '[2*$f+($i&&$i<2*$k)]).$r.$c;}return$m;}
```

**breakdown**

```
function h($n)
{
    for($m=['|'];$k++<$n;)
    {
        array_unshift($m,$m[]=str_repeat(' -'[$f=$k&1],2*$k-1));
        foreach($m as$i=>&$r)
            $r=($c='||- '[2*$f+($i&&$i<2*$k)]).$r.$c;
    }
    return$m;
}
```

**ungolfed**

```
function ihih($n)
{
    $m=['|'];                   // iteration 0
    for($k=1;$k<=$n;$k++)       // loop $k from 1 to $n
    {
        $f=$k&1;                        // flag for odd iterations
        // add lines:
        $r=str_repeat(' -'[$f],2*$k-1); // new line: ' ' for even, '-' for odd iterations
        $m[]=$r;                                // append
        array_unshift($m,$r);                   // prepend
        // add columns:
        foreach($m as$i=>&$r)           // for each line
        {
            $c='| '[$f];                        // '|' for even, ' ' for odd iterations
            if($f && (!$i || $i==2*$k)) $c='-'; // '-' in corners for odd iterations
            $r=$c.$r.$c;                        // prepend and append character
        }
    }
    return $m;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 150 bytes

```perl
sub h{my$i=pop;my$c=$i%2?$":'|';return(map{"$c$_$c"}h($i-1)),$i%2?'-'x($i*2+1):$c.$"x($i*2-1).$c if$i;()}say for reverse(@q=h<>),$q[0]=~s/---/ | /r,@q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYztCoIwGEZvZcgbm@X8Av9oljfQFUSEjYmDdHPTSNIuvTXq33MOh0dxfc@sNdMNta9uBlEqqQo3WAlikx7By/GCC83HSfekq9XLAwZXYN7aEhA08f3gF2KKn05s013i58BC8P7oihAYEg2IgvirqWfUSI00f3BtOKmGst0f3Mdwji/l20SU0ggtKNJBNVibfaQaheyNpacsjJP4Cw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 110 bytes

```hs
f 0=["|"]
f n|odd n=g ' '!n$'-'|1>0=g '|'$id!n$' '
g c=map$(c:).(++[c])
(g!n)c|p<-g.f$n-1=(:p)<>pure$c<$head p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYuxasMwFEV3f8VNEEgiWNilQwmSlxTaoZk6hlCELDum9pOQlULA/@7Gwx3O4dybnX/9OK7DFEPKeLfZqnOgMLQQQjdSoiwRaHyAvPPzbNMDXUj4@Dzhz6d5CASNN/Wq6rVDZS77ZX8tOtAS2hZkenDwHTFe8qVuqo0XzoZ2U@BFD2cmG5lwR6nE4XBxV1mIfkfSLVGXveoYlbURxyh1E@/JM6fZzdsWcZ3sQDB43s8/iPf8ndMXQaF7Lm2J0Rq9z6dA2VOe15fqHw)

#### Explanation/Ungolfed

The helper function `g` takes a character and a list of strings, it then pre- and appends that character to each string:

```hs
g c = map (\s-> [c] ++ s ++ [c])
```

Next the operator `(!)` takes a function (`g`), a number (`n`) and a character (`c`). It then computes the output for `n-1`, applies the function `g` to it and adds a string of the same width consisting of `c`s to the beginning and end:

```hs
(g ! n) c | prev <- g $ f (n-1), ln <- [c | _ <- head p]
          = [ln] ++ prev ++ [ln]
```

With these we'r ready to generate the outputs recursively, first we need to cover the base case:

```hs
f 0 = ["|"]
```

And then the recursion:

```hs
-- for odd n: the previous output needs a space at the end and beginning and then a string of '-' characters at the top and bottom
f n | odd n     = (g ' ' ! n) '-'
-- for even n: the previous output needs a line of spaces at the top and bottom and then each line needs to be enclosed with '|' characters
    | otherwise = g '|' $ (id ! n ) ' '
```

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 37 bytes

```
f=:{&' |-'@*@(-:@=+<-2&|@>.)"{~@:|@i:
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##y/r/P83WqlpNXaFGV91By0FD18rBVttG10itxsFOT1Opus7BqsYh0wqoTMFUQUFBKV4hNTkjXx3IUwcA)