# Hate/love conundrum

Tags: code-golf, string

## Challenge description

In this challenge, we only consider `love` and `hate` as feelings. If we want to utter a **feeling expression** of order `N`, we alternate between these two (starting with `hate`):

```
order | expression

1       I hate it.
2       I hate that I love it.
3       I hate that I love that I hate it.
4       I hate that I love that I hate that I love it.
```

The pattern follows for every positive integer `N`. Given `N`, output the correspoinding feeling expression of order `N`.

## Notes

- Full stop (`.`) at the end of the expression is mandatory,
- Trailing and leading whitespaces (including newlines) are permitted,
- Output for a non-positive or non-integer `N` is undefined,
- This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, so make your code as short as possible!

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/90287/48934).

Comment: Quite confused. So is `order` the input, and `expression` the output?

Comment: @Whothehellisthat Yes, exactly. (Welcome to PPCG! :))

Comment: @Whothehellisthat: Yes. You may take input through stdin, though it's often shorter to define a method (function), as you can see in the submissions below.

Comment: I hate that I love this question and its answers!

Comment: Is it okay if each component of a "feeling expression" of order `N` is separated by new lines instead of spaces, i.e `I hate it \n I love it` (where `\n` is the new line)?

Comment: @R.Kap: you mean like `I hate that \n I love that \n I hate it.` ? No.

Answer (score 21):

## Python, 54 bytes

```python
lambda n:("I hate that I love that "*n)[:12*n-5]+"it."
```

- Python 2: [Ideone it!](http://ideone.com/QApTy4)
- Python 3: [Ideone it!](http://ideone.com/Jo3Kap)

Comment: Ported to Haskell: `f n=take(12*n-5)(cycle"I hate that I love that ")++"it."` (56 bytes)

Answer (score 15):

### [CJam](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/), 36 bytes

```
ri{"hatlov"3/='IS@"e that "}/2<"it."
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=cml7ImhhdGxvdiIzLz0nSVNAImUgdGhhdCAifS8yPCJpdC4i&input=NA)

#### Explanation

```
ri            e# Read input and convert to integer N.
{             e# For each i from 0 to N-1...
  "hatlov"3/  e#   Push ["hat" "lov"].
  =           e#   Use i as a cyclic index into this array to alternate between
              e#   "hat" and "lov".
  'IS         e#   Push character 'I' and a space.
  @           e#   Pull "hat" or "lov" on top of it.
  "e that "   e#   Push "e that "
}/
2<            e#   Truncate the last "e that " to just "e ".
"it."         e#   Push "it."
```

Answer (score 7):

## C, <s>83</s> <s>76</s> <s>75</s> 74 bytes

*Thanks to @Leaky Nun for saving 11 bytes and adding 4 bytes!*
*Thanks to @YSC for saving a byte!*

```c
i;f(n){for(i=0;n--;)printf("I %se %s",i++%2?"lov":"hat",n?"that ":"it.");}
```

[Try it on Ideone](https://ideone.com/S5ql74)

Comment: `i=0;while(n--)` -> `for(i=0;n--;)` saves 1 char.

Answer (score 6):

### Javascript (ES6), <s>75</s> <s>73</s> 70 bytes

```
n=>[...Array(n)].map((_,i)=>i&1?'I love':'I hate').join` that `+' it.'
```

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to Neil*
*Saved 3 bytes thanks to Whothehellisthat*

#### Test

```js
let f =
n=>[...Array(n)].map((_,i)=>i&1?'I love':'I hate').join` that `+' it.'

console.log(f(1))
console.log(f(2))
console.log(f(3))
console.log(f(4))
```

Comment: Save 3 bytes: `['I hate','I love'][i&1]` -> `i&1?'I love':'I hate'`

Comment: @Whothehellisthat - Thanks! I missed that one.

Answer (score 5):

## Java 8, 91 bytes

```
i->{for(int j=0;j++<i;)System.out.printf("I %se %s",j%2>0?"hat":"lov",j<i?"that ":"it.");};
```

## Ungolfed Test Program

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Consumer<Integer> c = i -> {
        for (int j = 0; j++ < i;) {
            System.out.printf("I %se %s", j % 2 > 0 ? "hat" : "lov", j < i ? "that " : "it.");
        }
    };

    c.accept(1);
    c.accept(2);
    c.accept(3);
}
```

Comment: Why not remove the whitespace? `c=i->for(...)`

Comment: I simply forgot.

Comment: Nice, you've beat me to it. +1 And probably shorter than my answer would be. PS: I would indicate this as 'Java 8' instead of just 'Java'. Not mandatory however, just personal preference from me since I usually write my answers in Java 7 (and since Java 9 is incoming).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen You tell me this everytime ;) fine

Comment: @SeanBean Well, usually I already have my Java 7 answer, and you post a shorter answer, which can then most of the time be golfed even more. ;P (This time I can't find anything to make it shorter, though. But perhaps someone else is able to do so.)

Comment: You can use `String.format` instead of `System.out.printf`, making the lambda a `Function<Integer, String>` instead of a `Consumer<Integer>`

Comment: @CAD97 I believe printing it and not returning it is part of the spec?

Comment: @CAD97 Doesn't that add some additional bytes for `return`-ing the String?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen function output is an acceptable output, but yes, you're correct; I misread and can't test right now.

Comment: Question from avenger12: Hows does the Java 8 solution for the Love/Hate Conundrum code golf work? If j=0 at the start of the loop wouldn't the boolean j++ < i == false and thus the body of the for loop wouldn't execute? Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Comment: @Maltysen: `for (int j = 0; j++ < i;)` is essentially equivalent to `for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)`. `j++` increments the `j` variable each time.

Answer (score 5):

### Mathematica, 63 bytes

```
"I love"["I hate"][[#~Mod~2]]&~Array~#~Riffle~" that "<>" it."&
```

Comment: I'm loving the head extraction there, really clever.

Comment: @ASimmons [It's actually quite an old trick](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/46875/8478) (which I didn't even come up with myself), but I definitely don't get to use it often enough. ;)

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 25 bytes

```
“ṅɠT5“£ẏkg⁷»ṁj“¥ıQ»ṙ1“it.
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCc4bmFyaBUNeKAnMKj4bqPa2figbfCu-G5gWrigJzCpcSxUcK74bmZMeKAnGl0Lg&input=&args=NA)

### Explanation

```
                             Input: n, a number.
“ṅɠT5“£ẏkg⁷»                 Compressed string array [' I hate', ' I love']
            ṁ                Cycle for n repetitions.
             j“¥ıQ»          Join by compressed string ' that'.
                   ṙ1        Rotate left once: move the initial space to the end.
                     “it.    Implicitly print the result, then print 'it.'
```

Comment: I need an explanation for this.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>34</s> <s>32</s> 27 bytes

Saved 5 bytes thanks to [Adnan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/34388/adnan).

```
“I«¢€Š I„Î€Š “×¹12*5-£…it.«
```

**Explanation**

```
“I«¢€Š I„Î€Š “               # "I hate that I love that "
              ×              # repeat input nr of times
               ¹12*5-£       # take the first input*12-5 chars of string above
                      …it.«  # append "it."
                             # implicitly display
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCcScKrwqLigqzFoCBJ4oCew47igqzFoCDigJzDl8K5MTIqNS3Co-KApml0LsKr&input=NA)

Answer (score 4):

## R, 79 bytes

```
n=scan();for(i in n:1)cat(if((i+n)%%2)"I love"else"I hate",if(i>1)"that "else"it.")
```

Luckily in R, the default separator for `cat` is a space.

(Edited from original 73 byte version which didn't quite solve the problem.)

Comment: Neat use of the `for` loop and `%%`. +1

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina](http://github.com/mbuettner/retina), <s>42</s> 38 bytes

Thanks to Leaky Nun for helping me golf it!

```
11
1I love n
1
I hate n
n$
it.
n
that
```

Input is taken in unary.

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=MTEKMUkgbG92ZSBuCjEKSSBoYXRlIG4KbiQKaXQuCm4KdGhhdCA&input=MTExMTE)

**Explanation**

```
11
1I love n
```

Replace every pair of `1`s with `1I love n`.

```
1
I hate n
```

Replace the remaining `1`s with `I hate n`.

```
n$
it.
n
that
```

Replace the `n` at the end of the line with `it.` and every other n with `that` .

Comment: You can save four more by dropping `l`: http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=MTEKMUkgbG92ZSBuCjEKSSBoYXRlIG4KbiQKaXQuCm4KdGhhdCA&input=MTExMTE

Comment: @MartinEnder: I think I ninja'd you to that edit :P

Comment: Timestamps say you were 9 seconds late. :P

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript (ES5), <strike>99</strike> 94 bytes

```
function(c){for(d="",b=0;b<c;++b)d+=(b%2?"I love ":"I hate ")+(b==c-1?"it.":"that ");return d}
```

Saved 5 bytes thanks to Leaky Nun.

OLD 99 byte solution:

```
function(c){for(d="",b=0;b<c;++b)d+=(0==b%2?"I hate":"I love")+" "+(b==c-1?"it.":"that ");return d}
```

Another 98 byte solution:

```
function(d){for(c=[],b=0;b<d;++b)c.push(["love","hate"][b%2]);return"I "+c.join(" that I ")+" it"}
```

My code before minification:

```
function a(n){
  var hate="I hate",love="I love",it="it ",that="that ",out="";
  for(var i=0;i<n;++i){out+=(i%2==0?hate:love)+" "+(i==n-1?it+".":that)}return out;
}
```

Comment: `function(c){for(d="",b=0;b<c;++b)d+=(b%2?"I love ":"I hate ")+(b==c-1?"it.":"that ");return d}`

Answer (score 1):

## php, <s>64</s> 62 bytes

```
<?=str_pad("",$argv[1]*12-5,"I hate that I love that ")."it.";
```

Unfortunately I couldn't work out a way to avoid repeating the " that I ", or at least no way to do it in less than 7 bytes.

edit: saved 2 bytes thanks to @Jörg Hülsermann

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 70 bytes

```
g 1="I hate";g n=g(n-1)++" that "++cycle["I love",g 1]!!n
(++" it.").g
```

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell v2+, 64 bytes

```
((1..$args[0]|%{('I love','I hate')[$_%2]})-join' that ')+' it.'
```

Rather straightforward. Loops from `1` up to the input `$args[0]`, each iteration placing either `'I love'` or `'I hate'` on the pipeline, based on a pseudo-ternary for modulo-2 (i.e., it alternates back and forth, starting with `'I hate'`). Those strings are encapsulated in parens and `-join`ed with `' that '` to smush them together, then string concatenation `' it.'` at the end.

#### Test Cases

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> 1..5|%{.\hate-love-conundrum.ps1 $_}
I hate it.
I hate that I love it.
I hate that I love that I hate it.
I hate that I love that I hate that I love it.
I hate that I love that I hate that I love that I hate it.
```

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, <s>62</s> <s>54</s> 50 bytes

```
$_="I xe tx "x$_;s/tx $/it./;s/x/++$.%4?hat:lov/ge
```

(credit to [@Ton Hospel](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/51507/ton-hospel))

Demo: http://ideone.com/zrM27p

#### Previous solutions:

```
$_="I xe that "x$_;s/x/$@++&1?lov:hat/ge;s/\w+.$/it./
```

(credit to [@Dada](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/55508/dada))

Run with `perl -pE '$_="I xe that "x$_;s/x/$@++&1?lov:hat/ge;s/\w+.$/it./'`

#### First solution (only this was mine)

```
for$x(1..<>){$_.=' I '.($x%2?hat:lov).'e that'}s/\w+$/it./;say
```

In parts:

```
for $x (1..<>) {
   $_ .= ' I '.($x % 2 ? hat : lov).'e that'
}
s/\w+$/it./;
say
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/mosnVz

Comment: Hi and welcome to PPCG. Nice answer. Here is a shorter solution though (54 bytes) : `perl -pE '$_="I xe that "x$_;s/x/$@++&1?lov:hat/ge;s/\w+.$/it./'`.

Comment: What does this part mean `$@++&1`? For `@+` perldoc says "holds the offsets of the ends of the last successful submatches in the currently active dynamic scope" which doesn't make much sense for me. As I understand, you use this array in scalar context ($@+ - are you dereferencing it?) to get the number of elements and then add (+) the matched string (&1). No no no I knew I shouldn't have posted to PPCG it's too obfuscated :D

Comment: `$@` is just a scalar (I could have used `$x` or any other scalar), `++` is the increment operator, and `&1` is roughly the same as `%2`. So it's basically the same as `$x++%2`.

Comment: So you're using `@` for scalar variable name; &1 for "and"ing the last bit to check if it's even (and not a backreference as I thought). Ok understood now, thanks.

Comment: Nice solution. You can gain a few more bytes by using `$|--`  as a toggle instead of `$@++%2`

Comment: `$_="I xe tx "x$_;s/tx $/it./;s/x/++$.%4?hat:lov/ge` is even better

Comment: @TonHospel a look to perldoc shows that you use the `$.` variable only to use that it's equal to `1` in the beginning (i.e. to avoid doing `$a = 1;`)? That's cool.

Answer (score 1):

## Bash + coreutils, 106 bytes:

```
for i in `seq $1`;{ printf "I %s %s " `((i%2>0))&&echo hate||echo love` `((i==$1))&&echo it.||echo that`;}
```

Simply creates a sequence starting at `1` up to and including the input integer using the `seq` built-in, and then iterates through it one by one, first outputting `hate` if the value of the iteration variable, `i`, is not divisible by `2` and `love` otherwise. In the same iteration, it then chooses to output `that` if `i` is not equal to the input value, and `it.` otherwise.

[Try It Online! (Ideone)](http://ideone.com/fdCFXy)

Comment: Better put the command substitutions directly in `printf`'s string and use no format specifiers. Is pointless to compare whether `i%2` is greater than 0. I you reverse the commands in the list, you can use less than comparison instead of `i==$1`: `for i in \`seq $1\`;{ printf "I \`((i%2))&&echo hat||echo lov\`e \`((i<$1))&&echo that||echo it.\` ";}`. By the way, we usually label such solutions as Bash + coreutils, because the use of `seq`.

Answer (score 1):

## ///, <s>60</s> 57 bytes

```
/!/I hate //T/that //
/it.//00/!TI love T//Tit./it.//0/!/
```

*-3 bytes thanks to m-chrzan*

Input in unary with trailing new line.

[Try it online!](http://slashes.tryitonline.net/#code=LyEvSSBoYXRlIC8vVC90aGF0IC8vCi9pdC4vLzAwLyFUSSBsb3ZlIFQvL1RpdC4vaXQuLy8wLyEvMDAwCg&input=)

Comment: You could add `/T/that /` to the beginning and replace all instances of `that ` with `T`.

Answer (score 0):

### R, <strike>92</strike> 90 bytes

An R adaptation of @Leaky Nun's python answer. Working with strings in R is tedious as always.

```
n=scan();cat(rep(strsplit("I hate that I love that ","")[[1]],n)[6:(n*12)-5],"it.",sep="")
```

This could probably be golfed further though.

Edit: saved 2 bytes by changing:

`[1:((n*12)-5)]`to `[6:(n*12)-5]`

Comment: It works out better to loop instead; see my alternative R solution.

Answer (score 0):

### C, 96 Bytes

```
c;f(i){printf("I hate");for(;c<i+1/2-1;c++)printf(" that I %s",c&1?"hate":"love");puts(" it.");}
```

I didn't see the above solution from Releasing Helium Nuclei which is better.

Answer (score 0):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 37 bytes

```
:"2@o3]Qv'hate I that it. love'Ybw)Zc
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=OiIyQG8zXVF2J2hhdGUgSSB0aGF0IGl0LiBsb3ZlJ1lidylaYw&input=NA)

#### Explanation

The code is based on the following mapping from numbers to strings:

```
0: 'love'
1: 'hate'
2: 'I'
3: 'that'
4: 'it.'
```

The program pushes numbers to the string in groups of three: `2`, `0`, `3`; then `2`, `1`, `3`; then `2`, `0`, `3`; ... as many times as the input `n`. After that, the final `3` is transformed into a `4`, the mapping is applied to transform numbers to strings, and the strings are joined using space as separator.

```
:                         % Input n implicitly. Push range [1 2 ... n]
"                         % For each
  2                       %   Push 2
  @o                      %   Iteration index modulo 2: pushes 0 or 1
  3                       %   Push 3
]                         % End
Q                         % Add 1 to the last 3
v                         % Concatenate stack contents into a numeric column vector
'hate I that it. love'    % Push this string
Yb                        % Split at spaces. Gives a cell array of five strings
w                         % Swap to move numeric vector to top
)                         % Index cell array of strings with that vector. Indexing
                          % is 1-based and modular, so 0 refers to the last string.
                          % This gives a cell array of (repeated) strings
Zc                        % Join those strings by spaces. Display implicitly
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 68 bytes

```js
f=(n,i)=>n?(i?' that I ':'I ')+(i&1?'love':'hate')+f(n-1,-~i):' it.'

document.write('<pre>'+[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 100 ].map(c=>c+': '+f(c)).join`\n`);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Lua , 75 Bytes

```
n=io.read();print(('I hate that I love that '):rep(n):sub(1,n*12-5)..'it.')
```

Comment: Instead of static methods better use instance methods: `('I hate that I love that '):rep(n):sub(1,n*12-5)`. And would look nicer if you concatenate "it." to the end, because `print()` outputs its parameters separated by tab.

Comment: The ';' between io.read() and print is unneeded, and arg[2] is a valid input method for lua scripts, which is the first command line argument.

Answer (score 0):

## C#, <s>85</s> 83 bytes

```
string f(int n,int m=2)=>"I "+(1>m%2?"hat":"lov")+(m>n?"e it.":"e that "+f(n,m+1));
```

Recursively constructs the string, using an optional parameter to keep track of which hate/love and how many to append.

*-2 bytes from [this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/173/tips-for-code-golfing-in-c/84382#84382) for checking the evenness/oddness of a number.*

#### No optional parameter solution, <s>87</s> <s>86</s> 84 bytes

```
string h(int n)=>"I "+(0<n?"hat":"lov")+(2>n&-2<n?"e it.":"e that "+h(0<n?~n+2:~n));
```

This one does the same thing except determines which hate/love to append based on whether the parameter is positive or negative. Each iteration the parameter approaches zero, alternating sign.

Answer (score 0):

## Thue, 100 bytes

```
@::=:::
>##::=>$.
$::=~I hate that I love 
>.#::=>&#
&::=~that 
>#<::=~I hate it.
>.<::=~it.
::=
>@<
```

Takes input as unary. (A string of n `#`s)

Answer (score 0):

### Pyke, 36 bytes

```
2/"I hate ""I love "]*"that "J"it."+
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=2%2F%22I+hate+%22%22I+love+%22%5D%2a%22that+%22J%22it.%22%2B&input=3)

```
2/                                   -    input/2
                     *               -   ^ * v
  "I hate ""I love "]                -    ["I hate ", "I love "]
                      "that "J       -  "that ".join(^)
                              "it."+ - ^+"it."
```

Also 36 bytes

```
12*5+.daෆ   ű   l5d+12"I ":Q*<"it."+
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=12%2a5%2B.d%05a%E0%B7%86%09%C5%B1%09l5d%2B12%22I+%22%3AQ%2a%3C%22it.%22%2B&input=4) (Link uses `X` instead of `I`, [this](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=12*5%2B.d%05%0A%E0%B7%86%09%C5%B1%09l5d%2B12%22I+%22%3AQ*%3C%22it.%22%2B&input=4) should work for the same amount of bytes offline where you can literally use those bytes. Online `\r` gets automatically replaced with `\n`)

Answer (score 0):

## ><> (Fish), 82 Bytes

```
' I'oov.2coo<;oooo' it.'<
'ahv'v>'et'
oop26<^ooooo^o' that I '^!?:-1oo
'ol^'^>'ev'
```

Doubt it's very efficient, but it seems to more or less work. Input is via the starting stack, which makes the score 85 Bytes if you include the size of the `-v` argument required to do so.

[Try it online!](https://fishlanguage.com/playground/JTWzGWskTR7KWfoz3)

Answer (score 0):

## [///](http://esolangs.org/wiki////), 68 bytes

```
/@/1\/#love //%/hate//#/that I //%1i/% i//I %1/I % //1@#% //@/I %1it.
```

Input in unary - add more `1`s in the last section.

[Try it online!](http://slashes.tryitonline.net/#code=L0AvMVwvI2xvdmUgLy8lL2hhdGUvLyMvdGhhdCBJIC8vJTFpLyUgaS8vSSAlMS9JICUgLy8xQCMlIC8vQC9JICUxMTExMWl0Lg&input=)

Answer (score 0):

### dc, 75 bytes

```
?[1-lbP[I lov]P]sa[e that ]sb[[e it.]Pq]sc[1-[I hat]Pd2%1=ad1>clbPlxx]dsxx
```

We're really just printing one chunk of string at a time here, and not leaving any garbage on the stack. This is great, we don't need to waste any bytes dealing with a register for our counter.

```
?                              #Input, works as our decrement counter
[1-lbP[I lov]P]sa              #Macro 'a' decrements our counter, prints string 'b', 
                               #then prints 'I lov'
[e that ]sb                    #String 'b'
[[e it.]Pq]sc                  #Macro 'c' prints the tail end of our message and quits
[1-                            #I'll unfold our main macro here; first step is to 
                               #decrement our counter
   [I hat]P                    #We always start by hating 'it,' no conditional needed
           d2%1=a              #Check the oddness of our counter; execute 'a' if odd
                 d1>c          #Check our counter; If we're done, execute 'c'
                     lbPlxx]   #Otherwise, print 'b' again and start this macro ('x') over
dsxx                           #Stores the above macro as 'x' and runs it.
```

Answer (score 0):

### Julia, 91 Bytes

Thought I add a julia solution:

```
f(N)=string("I hate ",join(["that I love that I hate " for _ in 1:N-1])[1:12*(N-1)],"it."))
```